# Como verificar se um trecho de uma string está em algum item do array

Tags: php

Alguém sabe como verificar se uma referência ou string está em uma array? Eu tentei deste método e não funcionou

```
$array = "facebook.com, google.com, twitter.com";
$ref = "http://m.facebook.com";
$arrayIds = explode(',', $array);

if(isset($ref) && (strstr($ref,  $arrayIds) !== false)) {
    echo "sim: ";
} else {
    echo "não";
}
```

Obrigado

Comment: Duas coisas: 1 - Que o array, na realidade não é um array, mas uma string. A escrita correta do array seria  `$array = array("facebook.com", "google.com", "twitter.com");` 2 - Que a referencia informada também não existe no "Array".

Comment: Certo @AdrianoLuz , mas tem como ser daquele jeito? `$array = "facebook.com, google.com, twitter.com";` porque aquilo está no banco de dados, só dei um exemplo ali de como está na tabela.

Comment: poder até pode, caso seja um exemplo ou exercício. Mas é preciso que você entenda que o seu banco não está respeitando a Forma Normal 1

Comment: @FernandoOliveira tomei a liberdade de corrigir o título. Estava levando à respostas erradas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu exemplo a função `strstr`não funcionou pois ela trabalha para retornar um trecho de uma string contida em outra, não valendo para `array`.

**Então o que fazer?**

Se a necessidade for verificar se dentro do `array` `$arrayIds` existe uma string que contenha parte de outra, eu sugiro que você combine `array_map` com a função desejada. Daí em seguida, utilize `in_ array` para ver se existe alguma ocorrência verdadeira para essa função.

Um exemplo, quero saber se `"bola"` existe em alguma parte das strings que estão dentro do `array`.

Veja:

```
 $produtos = array(
     'bola vermelha',
     'boneca Barbie',
     'caneca de ouro'
 );

 // Essa função será executada em cada item do array acima

 $verifica_string = function ($value)
 {
       return strpos($value, 'bola') !== false;
 };

 $lista_de_verificacoes = array_map($verifica_string, $produtos);

 var_dump(in_array(true, $lista_de_verificacoes , true)); // Retornará "true" se "bola" existir no array
```

Você ainda opcionalmente pode utilizar a função `preg_grep` seguida de um `count` para saber se foram encontradas alguma referência. Creio que você terá que usar menos código nesse caso, mas terá que usar expressão regular:

```
   // Temos que escapar os valores por causa do "."

   $refRegex = sprintf('/%s/', preg_quote('facebook.com'));

   if (count(preg_grep($refRegex, $arrayIds))) > 0) {
     // tem a string
   }
```

Existe ainda uma terceira maneira, que é utilizando a função `array_filter`. Mas nesse caso, quando a situação é complexa, como a mostrada acima, eu sempre gosto de deixar uma função pronta para isso, caso seja necessário reutilizar:

```
 function array_contains_value($neddle, array $array)
 {

     return (boolean) count(array_filter($array, function ($value) use($neddle)
     {
          return strpos($value, $neddle) !== false;
     }));
 }
```

Na função acima eu uso as seguintes funções:

- `count` - Conta os valores do `array` ou de uma classe que implementa `Countable`
- `array_filter` - Remove os valores do `array` de acordo com o callback. Será removido se retornar `FALSE`
- `strpos` - Verifica se a string contém o trecho especificado.

Você poderia verificar assim:

```
 array_contains_value('facebook.com', ['www.facebook.com', 'www.google.com']);
```

Comment: Obrigado por comentar. Eu já tentei fazer deste método mas eu queria verificar se existe um pedaço da string na referência, porque no caso a referência é `http://m.facebook.com` e a string pra verificar é `facebook.com`.

Comment: Ah, sim. É simples. Vou editar a pergunta

Comment: Lembre-se: Se resolveu o problema, não esqueça de deixar o +1 ou marcar a pergunta como Util

Comment: Obrigado novamente, seu código é complexo mas eu entendi um pouco, eu consegui fazer do seu jeito, muito obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Um exemplo mais simples, creio que atenda você.

```
$array = "facebook.com, google.com, twitter.com";
$ref = "http://m.facebook.com";
$arrayIds = explode(',', $array);

if (in_array($ref,$arrayIds)){
    echo 'Existe';
}else{
    echo 'Não existe';
}
```

Comment: Desconsidere, li somente o enunciado da questão. Nos  comentários vi que não era o que precisava de fato

Answer (score -4):

Vamos fazer o inverso, vamos conferir se uma das entradas do array existe na variável de referencia, assim qualquer referencia que contenha facebook.com será válido

```
$array = "facebook.com, google.com, twitter.com";
$array = explode(trim(","),$array);
$ref = "http://m.facebook.com";
$flag = false;

foreach($array as $a){
if (preg_match("/{$a}/",$ref)){
       $flag = true;
   }
}

if($flag){
    echo 'sim';
}else{
    echo 'nao';
}
```

Comment: Seu código tem um grave problema. o Caractere `.` na expressão regular significa **tudo**. Você precisa escapá-lo. Do contrário, seu código causará um efeito negativo, causando problemas ao AP

Answer (score -4):

Criei esta função para fazer essa verificação.
Se algum item do array estiver contido na string de referência, retornará true. Do contrário, retornará false;

```
function match_array_in_string($needles, $string){
  foreach($needles AS $needle){
    if(stripos($string,$needle) !== false){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```